# ocaml unbound module after opam install

Tags: ocaml

Install the module [bigstringaf](https://github.com/inhabitedtype/bigstringaf) following:

```sh
opam pin add -n bigstringaf .
opam install --deps-only bigstringaf
opam install bigstringaf
```

Then I tested it using `make test` and successed, but when I tried in ocaml, it failed.
And I find the package using `ocamlfind list`

```sh
>ocaml
        OCaml version 4.09.0

# open Bigstringaf;;
Error: Unbound module Bigstringaf
# require "Bigstringaf";;
Error: Unbound value require
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is actually a toplevel command, meaning you need to write `#` before it. You also need to give it a package name which is different from the module name (in this case it's the same, just not capitalized).

```
# #require "bigstringaf";;
/home/oli/.opam/4.09.0/lib/bigarray-compat: added to search path
/home/oli/.opam/4.09.0/lib/bigarray-compat/bigarray_compat.cma: loaded
/home/oli/.opam/4.09.0/lib/bigstringaf: added to search path
/home/oli/.opam/4.09.0/lib/bigstringaf/bigstringaf.cma: loaded
# open Bigstringaf;;
```